# How to convert data passed by delegate to different values?

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, delegates

What i am trying to do is multiply and add the data passed from the delegate to get the sales tax and the total in the labels `salesTaxLbl` and `totalLbl` of the `AdditionalCostsController`

The func in the AdditionalCostsDelegate that passes data from the cartTotalLbl(TotalFooter) to the subtotalLbl(AdditionalCostsController) has no issues passing data to the label

I keep getting an error when I try to multiply inside the value ***taxes*** and when I try to add inside the value ***total***

as soon as I press the `feesBtn(additionalFeesOnClicked)` I get an error code on either taxes or total in the `AdditionalCostsDelegate` with the error saying:

***Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

my Delegate:

```
protocol AdditionalCostsDelegate: class {
    func onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: String)
}
```

code palced in my `TotalFooter` cell to pass the delegate

```
weak var additionalCostsDelegate: AdditionalCostsDelegate? = nil

@IBAction func additionalFeesOnClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.additionalCostsDelegate?.onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: cartTotalLbl.text!)
}
```

code placed in `CartViewController` to handle delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let totalFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TotalFooter") as! TotalFooter

   //...... ->

   <-  ...... // code used to get overallTotal

    totalFooter.cartTotalLbl.text = String(overallTotal!)
    totalFooter.additionalCostsDelegate = self

    return totalFooter
}
```

Delegate used to pass data to `AdditionalCostsController`

```
extension CartViewController: AdditionalCostsDelegate {
    func onTouchAdditionalCostsInfo(info: String) {
        let popUp = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdditionalCostsVC") as! AdditionalCostsController

        self.present(popUp, animated: true) {

            let taxes = Float(info)! * Float(0.0825) //where im getting my error ***
            let total = Float(info)! + Float(taxes)  //where im getting my error ***

            // convert to currency
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

            // currency conversion
            let salesTax = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(taxes)))
            let totalFee = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(total)))


            // labels
            popUp.subtotalLbl.text = info

            popUp.salesTaxLbl.text = salesTax
            popUp.totalLbl.text = totalFee
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use the debugger to see what is the value of `info`?

Comment: Don't use ! unless you are willing to have a crash.  Conditionally convert `info` to a `Float` - but yes, check what value `info` has

Comment: ***@Sweeper*** the value of info is the total of the items in the CartViewController. so the value of info could be anything. But I might be a little confused with your questing can you better explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not proper way to type cast String to Float, what you can do is create an extension to get a float value from the string like this,

```
extension String {
    var floatValue: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }
}
```

and use it like this :

```
let infoFloatValue = info.floatValue

let taxes = infoFloatValue * Float(0.0825)
let total = infoFloatValue + Float(taxes)
```

Comment: the code succeeds at passing the data to the AdditionalCostsVC , but im getting ***"0.0"*** (without the numberFormatter) and ***"$0.00"*** (with the numberFormatter) when I run the code in both the ```salesTaxLbl``` and ```totalLbl```

Comment: before getting the float value, print the info value, there is a problem with the value you're passing @Evelyn

Comment: ***@Sumeet.Jain*** the info value is passing data fine both when I print it and when I pass it into the subtotalLbl could it be something else? I'll keep testing it out and keep you posted to see what is wrong

Comment: Bridging to `NSString` *is not proper way to type cast String to Float* either. Don't do that. The proper Swift way is  `let taxes = Float(info) ?? 0.0 ` or optional binding depending on the context.

Comment: I did a typo it was an error on my end your method worked thank you